# Current path didn't match the url patterns - Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-urls

I am unable to get the url redirected to one of the patterns defined in the url routing file.

*web.py*

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib import admin

from heyurl import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('store', views.store, name='store'),
    path('/metrics/', views.get_month_metrics, name= 'metrics'),
]
```

*views.py* (Includes the function that is getting called along with the libraries included)

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Url, Click

from django.core.validators import URLValidator, ValidationError
from heyurl.utils import db_services, helper
from django_user_agents.utils import get_user_agent
from django.template.defaulttags import register
from datetime import datetime


def get_month_metrics(request, url):
    today = datetime.now()
    ident = Url.objects.filter(short_url= url)
    ident = ident[0].id

# GETTING THE CLICKS THIS MONTH
clicks_this_month = Click.objects.filter(url=ident, created_at__year=today.year,
                                         created_at__month=today.month)

# TOTAL CLICKS PER BROWSER
safari = Click.objects.filter(url=ident, browser__contains='safari')
chrome = Click.objects.filter(url=ident, browser__contains='chrome')
firefox = Click.objects.filter(url=ident, browser__contains='firefox')


# TOTAL CLICKS PER PLATFORM
mobile = Click.objects.filter(url=ident, platform='Mobile')
pc = Click.objects.filter(url=ident, platform='PC')

#CONTEXT TO DISPLAY ON DATA PANEL
context = {
    'url': url,
    'clicks': len(clicks_this_month),
    'safari': len(safari),
    'chrome': len(chrome),
    'firefox': len(firefox),
    'mobile': len(mobile),
    'pc': len(pc),
}

return render(request, 'heyurl/metrics.html', context)
```

Now I tried hardcoding and supplied the exact pattern that it says is missing by changing the *web.py* as follows

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('store', views.store, name='store'),
    path('RQvw4/metrics/', views.get_month_metrics, name= 'metrics'),
]
```

and it gives me the following error
[image: error after hardcoding url]

Comment: You've defined your view to take two parameters: `request` and `url`.  `request` is a standard parameter, and Django knows how to call your view and pass in that argument.  But `url` is a parameter that you made up yourself, and Django doesn't know how to pass it to your view function.  Where were you expecting the `url` value to come from?

Comment: Url is supplied from the main template page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you expect to get `RQvw4` as `url` - so you should define path with parameter `<url>` like

```
path('<url>/metrics/', ...)
```

And then you should keep `url` in function

```
def get_month_metrics(request, url):
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you hardcode

```
path('RQvw4/metrics/',...)
```

then it doesn't know that you want to assign `RQvw4` to `url`.
It would need to hardcode this value also in function

```
def get_month_metrics(request, url="RQvw4"):
```

But it still would need to use `path('<url>/metrics/', ...)` for other urls.

Comment: Thanks so much. `<url>/metrics/` was what I was missing all along.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `url` argument from `get_month_metrics()` and access url using `request.path`. It should look like this:

```
def get_month_metrics(request):
    url = request.path
    # rest of your code
```

Comment: doesnt work gives an error of  `Index Error :  ident = ident[0].id`

Comment: @mishsx now you have totally different problem - now you get url but it gives empty result for `filter()` because probably it checks `short_url="RQvw4/metrics"` instead of `short_url="RQvw4"`. I think you should define `path('<url>/metrics/', ...)` to get `RQvw4` as `url`. Maybe first use `print()` to see what you have in variables.

Comment: @mishsx does `RQvw4/metrics/` exist in your database?